# Get Transformation method and Parameters from coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, datum

I have data (vectors, and raster) that are in UTM coordinate system, and I need to reproject them to a local coordinate system. Unfortunately, I do not know the transformation method that I may use either the transformation parameters (there or seven parameters) :( 
However, I can get get some points surrounding the AOI in both UTM and equivalent local coordinate system.
My question is, how can I get the transformation parameters using these points and the UTM and local projection parameters to get the transformation method and parameters?

Comment: What program or library?

Comment: You wouldn't use the 3/7 parameter datum transformations methods,  unless there's only a datum change, but a 2D conformal or affine transformation.

Comment: I'm searching for a tool that reverse engineer the transformation tool, I can provide points in two different GCSs and I need to know the 3 / 7 parameters of transformation

Comment: @mkennedy There is a datum change